# Jquery Sortable. Adjusting CSS on Selected / Drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

Using Jquery Sortable. I want to do a simple css switch function so that I can change the background colour of the field I have selected (`<div class='bar-across'`) from a white to a yellow bg using a css class `.selected` (`<div class="bar-across selected">`) . When I release the mouse / click, I would like for it to return to its original state.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8emns7jn/)

#### HTML:

```
<div id="reorder-list">
  <div id="listItem_1" class="bar-across CF"><span class="handle">Drag</span>Item 1</div>
  <div id="listItem_2" class="bar-across CF"><span class="handle">Drag</span>Item 2</div>
  <div id="listItem_3" class="bar-across CF"><span class="handle">Drag</span>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

#### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reorder-list").sortable({
        placeholder: "destination",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        handle: '.handle',
        update: function () {
            var order = $('#reorder-list').sortable('serialize');
            $("#info").load("billboard-sort.php?" + order);
        }
    });
});
```

#### CSS:

```
.bar-across {
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    width: 100%;
}
#reorder-list div .handle {
    cursor: move;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    background:#0C6;
    padding: 10px;
}
.destination {
    background:#1c5dbb;
    width: inherited;
}
.selected {
    background:#FF0;
}
/* Clearfix
    ============================================================================ */

/* Clearfix */
 .CF:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.CF {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the events `start` and `stop` in the [Sortable API](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start). By using them, you can just add or remove your desired class to/from the current, dragged element. Access is possible via

```
$(ui.item).doStuff();
```

where `ui` is of course the second of the event callback parameter.